# Preallocating memory space for programs use

Tags: c++, memory-management

In my Windows' C++ program, I allocate several small objects on heap (thousands) by calling **new CMyClass()**

The performance seems to get affected due to this.

Is there a way to preallocate some minimum memory in heap for the program's use so that the OS starts allocating from this preallocated space when ever I call **new CMyClass()** to improve the performance?

Thanks.

Comment: See, for example, Small Object Allocator (http://books.google.com/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&lpg=PA94&ots=YRdKZrRk50&dq=alexandrescu%20small%20object%20allocator&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q=alexandrescu%20small%20object%20allocator&f=false)

Comment: Consider that allocating thousands of objects on the heap at startup might be indicative of a design flaw.  Maybe not, but something to consider.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be looking for a **memory pool** - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27487/Why-to-use-memory-pool-and-how-to-implement-it

Note that you can pre-allocate some memory and then use placement new to prevent multiple allocations.

Comment: I would indeed go for 'placement new', very elegant approach.